# what's the preferred way to perform user authentication and authorization in Clojure?

Tags: authentication, clojure, authorization

I've been working on a web app in Clojure as a side project, and I'm trying to figure out how to do user authentication and autherization. From the googling I've done, I heard about sandbar, but after reading the two blogposts on sandbar ([Part 1](http://formpluslogic.blogspot.com/2010/08/securing-web-applications-with-sandbar.html), [Part 2](http://formpluslogic.blogspot.com/2010/08/securing-clojure-web-applications-with.html)), I left with more questions than answers. I've looked at the [source code](https://github.com/4clojure/4clojure) for [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/), and from what I can tell, they roll their own, the problem is that the code's not commented very well, if at all. I'm thinking I need to roll my own system and use either sandbar or noir.session to pass user information around. Could someone please point me in the right direction? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Here's a useful talk on some of the problems with the state of security in Clojure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBL59w7fXw4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a look at the [4clojure login code](https://github.com/4clojure/4clojure/blob/develop/src/foreclojure/login.clj) and I think it is pretty clear how the implementation works. Basically it is the traditional HTTP authentication. Post user/pwd in form to a URL, check username and password and update the session with the user info that can be used for further requests to check whether this session is for a valid logged in user.

This is how most of the web app authentication works. Now this is "what to do" part of the situation, for "how to do" you can implement it your self using "primitive" features provided by the web framework or probably use some middle-ware that does this for you along with providing some hooks to customize the implementation a bit.

Answer (score 10):

Chas Emerick's [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend/) library is now available. It's still relatively new, but looks promising and quite well documented.

Answer (score 8):

For authentication, apart from the obvious "rolling your own", I found https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth to work well if you want to use OAUTH (e.g. via Twitter). Once you've acquired user information, storing it in some sort of session object (via [ring-middleware-session](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/wiki/Sessions) or similar abstractions) seems to be the obvious thing to do.

For authorization, the way described in the blog post you linked to - wrapping certain routes with an authorization middleware (or whatever abstraction your preferred web stack offers - e.g. `pre-route` in [Noir](http://webnoir.org)) works well.

Answer (score 5):

There's also an alternative to Friend called [Buddy](https://github.com/funcool/buddy).

*What is the difference with Friend?*

*Buddy authorization/authentication facilities are more low level and less opinionated that friend and allow build over them easy other high level abstractions. Technically, friend abstraction can be build on top of buddy*